# why using < or > on string give different ansers

Tags: python

`"27" > "8.0"`

is giving me False ?

am using a string to compare. could anyone please explain ?
I tried to understand but I coundnt

Comment: Strings aren't numbers and don't compare like numbers. (Would you expect "two" to come before "three" in the dictionary?)

Comment: how do you compare "abc" > "cdeFG" ?

Comment: If you were to put the strings `27 Down` and `8 Mile` in order, what order would you put them?

Answer (score 3):

When you compare strings, it compares them lexicographically, character by character. Since `"2"` is not greater than `"8"`, `"27" > "8.0"` is false.

If you want to compare them numerically, you have to convert them to numbers.

```
float("27") > float("8.0")
```

will give you `True`.